# How to append vector to numpy matrix based on its string name?

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic, append, names

I have asynchronous process with numerous numpy arrays' where their new values are coming arbitrarily and need to be appended. I am struggling with it for hours and would like to get sth like this:

```
class nbAppend():
    def __init__(self):
         pass

    def append(self,varName,varValues):
          self.varName = np.append(self.varName,varValues,axis=0) # !!! not feasible
```

so when for a numpy array x new values come, it should be updated in the sence 'x' = np.append('x',values,axis=0). I know there's solution with dictionaries, i.e.

```
np_add_rows = {}
def process_row(d, key,_cache=np_add_rows):
    # keep the rows for each key separate.
    lst = _cache.setdefault(key, [])
    lst.append(d)
```

but this work around slows down the code for 5-6x, which is unacceptable. So, how to append a vector to a numpy matrix based on its string name? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's hard to give an example due to asynchronous process, but will try to further support it. Say we have hundreds of variables, of which values are arbitrarily pushed to us. Since we do not know which variable will come and since it's not practical and efficient to write ```x = np.append(x,values) ``` for each of them, a function that updates an x variable based on its name 'x' would be useful. Hopefully it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: If you have access to the string form of the variable name, I don't see why something like `defaultdict(list)` wouldn't work while staying fast. Key look-up and appending to a list are O(1) while appending to an array is going to require a complete copy of the array to be made

Comment: The thing is that after new values are appended, analysis follows. I have tested solutions with dictionaries (also pandas)  as well as with lists, but are significantly slower (5-6x). So it turned out best to append new vectors to numpy matrix and do the analysis on it right away.

Comment: have you profiled it to see exactly what is causing the bottleneck and what are you doing in terms of analysis, because as the arrays grow larger, it will become much slower as you have to allocate more and more memory. If you must use an array, set a maximum size buffer so you don't have to copy every time new data comes in, and get rid of the old data once it's no longer needed

Comment: Generally we recommend list append over `np.append`.. It's faster and easier to start.  But if you have to do array operations before you've accumulated all elements that speed advantage be not be there.  Keep in mind that  `np.append` makes a new array each time, with a full copy.

Comment: The code itself is optimized, also keeping last needed rows is taken care of to keep memory low as possible. List append is faster then np.append, have proven it to myself while analysing the speed of the code, but since the analysis is highly vectorized numpy's library is very appropriate and would like to keep it, if possible.

Comment: It's not obvious why the 'string name' should cause any more of a problem if you are accumulating values in an array as opposed to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collecting arrays in a dictionary:

With a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
In [85]: dd = defaultdict(lambda : np.zeros(0, int))                                                 
In [86]: for i in ['aa','bb','cc','dd','aa','cc']: 
    ...:     dd[i] = np.concatenate([dd[i], np.arange(3)]) 
    ...:                                                                                             
In [87]: dd                                                                                          
Out[87]: 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {'aa': array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]),
             'bb': array([0, 1, 2]),
             'cc': array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]),
             'dd': array([0, 1, 2])})
```

or with a regular dict:

```
In [88]: dd = {}                                                                                     
In [89]: for i in ['aa','bb','cc','dd','aa','cc']: 
    ...:     arr = dd.get(i, np.zeros(0,int)) 
    ...:     dd[i] = np.concatenate([arr, np.arange(3)]) 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                             
In [90]: dd                                                                                          
Out[90]: 
{'aa': array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]),
 'bb': array([0, 1, 2]),
 'cc': array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]),
 'dd': array([0, 1, 2])}
```

The list equivalent:

```
In [93]: dd = defaultdict(list)                                                                      
In [94]: for i in ['aa','bb','cc','dd','aa','cc']: 
    ...:     dd[i].extend(np.arange(3)) 
    ...:                                                                                             
In [95]: dd                                                                                          
Out[95]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'aa': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
             'bb': [0, 1, 2],
             'cc': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
             'dd': [0, 1, 2]})
```

Normally this list version would be faster, but if at each iteration we had to do something like

```
acc.append(np.sum(dd[i]))
```

it could tip the timings in favor of the array accumulation, since it would save on the repeated conversion from list to array.